# How to implement multithreading

Tags: multithreading, clojure

**Game rules**

Consider a simple 2-player game played as follows: An even number of coins is laid out in a row. Taking turns, each player removes the coin on one of the ends of the row. The object is to have the highest value in coins when all coins have been taken.

Player one finds the sum of all of the even-numbered coins, and all the odd-numbered coins. If the sum of the odd numbered coins is higher, player one takes the leftmost coin; otherwise he takes the rightmost.

Player two has a choice, with an odd number of coins. So he tries taking a coin from both ends, to see which option would leave player 1 worse off.

**The problem**

I basically want to implement multitheading to this program. I am still very new to Clojure, and I couldn't really find any good material online, regarding multithreading, that could be applied to my program.

**The code**

```
(ns game.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn vector-from-string [s]
  (drop 1 (map read-string (clojure.string/split (clojure.string/trim-newline s) #" "))))

(defn string-from-file [f]
  (slurp f))

(defn sum-of-evens [v]
  (def evens (vector))
  (loop [v v, index 1]
    (when (seq v)
      (if (even? index)
        (def evens (conj evens (first v))))
      (recur (rest v) (inc index))))
  (reduce + evens))

(defn sum-of-odds [v]
  (def odds (vector))
  (loop [v v, index 1]
    (when (seq v)
      (if (odd? index)
        (def odds (conj odds (first v))))
      (recur (rest v) (inc index))))
  (reduce + odds))

(defn player-two [v p1score p2score]
  (if (not (empty? v))
    (if (> (max (sum-of-odds (drop 1 v)) (sum-of-evens (drop 1 v))) (max (sum-of-odds (drop-last v)) (sum-of-evens (drop-last v))))
      (player-one (drop-last v) p1score (+ p2score(last v)))
      (player-one (drop 1 v) p1score (+ p2score (first v))))
    (println "p1score" p1score "p2score" p2score)))

(defn player-one [v p1score p2score]
  (if (not (empty? v))
    (if (> (sum-of-odds v) (sum-of-evens v))
      (player-two (drop 1 v) (+ p1score (first v)) p2score)
      (player-two (drop-last v) (+ p1score (last v)) p2score))
    (println "p1score" p1score "p2score" p2score)))

(defn -main [& args]
  (let [v (vector-from-string (string-from-file "numbers.txt")) ]
    (player-one v 0 0)))
```

So `-main` runs the `player-one` function first, and `player-one` calls `player-two`, and they both continue on until the end of the program. I would like to somehow implement multithreading to speed up the executing of this game with a higher amount of starting coins.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is currently very unidiomatic.

A few remarks that hopefully help you getting into the right direction:

A `def` inside a `defn` (or `def`) is (almost) always wrong. You're thinking in terms of variable assignment and mutable variables here. This is not how Clojure works. Use variables in your recur instead, if you absolutely must, use a local atom (also almost always wrong, but less often wrong than `def` inside `defn`).

Your loops are unnecessarily complicated. You want to sum over the elements at even or odd indices?  Use a combination of `reduce`, `take-nth` and `rest`:

```
(take-nth 2 [1 2 3])
;=> (1 3)
(take-nth 2 (rest [1 2 3 4]))
;=> (2 4)
```

The whole things looks like you're compiling this over and over again and then run the JVM with it. Am I right?  The preferred way is to work at the REPL. How to access it, depends on which editing environment you use. There are many beginner-friendly REPLs out there. Gorilla REPL is one example.

Once you got your code and development workflow in better shape, you may want to explore functions like `pmap` and `future` for easy access to multi-threading. More advanced stuff involves a library called `core.async`, but that's probably not the ideal route for the beginner. You can also fall back to Java interop to create your threads. Again something that, while not really hard to do, requires a bit of experience with Clojure.

Hope that helps, even it is not a direct answer to your question.

Comment: Not only is using `def` inside functions unidiomatic, but altering namespace-level var bindings will make multithreading this code extremely difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the help in refactoring in my code a little bit. The `sum-of-odds` and `sum-of-evens` functions are lot more elegant now. And I am using a repl, specifically the lein repl. Another answerer on this thread mentioned that I wouldn't be able to explore multi-threading because my two functions `player-one` and `player-two` are mutually recursive. Do you agree with him? If not, how would I be able to implement multi-threading into my program?

Comment: Taylor did a really nice job refactoring your functions. Make sure you follow his train of thoughts on that. I also like his use of laziness with `cycle`. Make sure you understand this, too. And yes, the mutual recursion is working against multi-threading. Ask yourself, what d you want to model with threads and why. If the players should be threads, you needs some mechanism to coordinate them taking turns. I'd suggest you first get your Clojure knowledge and approaches a bit deeper before you move on to building multi-threaded apps with the Clojure primitives. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

First let's look at some issues in your example that will need to be addressed before parallelizing this code.

`sum-of-evens` is using `def` inside a function, which is almost always a mistake. This might seem to have the effect you want, but it's not the right way to achieve it. `def`s are typically used for namespace-level (at the same level as your function `defn`s) values. We can refactor `sum-of-evens` to not rely on unintentionally side-effecty behavior via `def`:

```
(defn sum-of-evens [v]
  (loop [v v
         index 1
         evens []]
    (if (seq v)
      (recur (rest v)
             (inc index)
             (if (even? index) ;; add a binding to loop, not a def
               (conj evens (first v))
               evens))         ;; pass unchanged value when necessary
      (reduce + evens))))
```

But we can further simplify this function with `keep-indexed`:

```
(defn sum-of-evens [coll]
  (->> coll
       (keep-indexed (fn [i v] (when (even? (inc i))
                                 v)))
       (apply +)))
```

And when we do the same for `sum-of-odds`, we can see the functions are nearly identical except for the condition they use: `odd?` vs. `even?`. We can make another function that takes a predicate function:

```
(defn sum-by-index-pred [f coll]
  (->> coll
       (keep-indexed (fn [i v] (when (f i) v)))
       (apply +)))
;; using partial application and function composition
(def sum-of-evens (partial sum-by-index-pred (comp even? inc)))
(def sum-of-odds (partial sum-by-index-pred (comp odd? inc)))
```

Looking at the implementation of `player-one` and `player-two`, they seem to be mutually recursive. I don't see how you could parallelize this to make it any faster because each turn is dependent on the previous turn's outcome; there's nothing to parallelize.

I'd suggest refactoring this so that your game rules and state are computed in one place, rather than mutually recursive functions.

```
(loop [scores (array-map :player-1 0 :player-2 0)
       turns (cycle (keys scores))
       vs (shuffle (range 100))]
  (if (seq vs)
    (let [higher-odds? (> (sum-of-odds vs) (sum-of-evens vs))
          scores (if higher-odds?
                   (update scores (first turns) + (first vs))
                   (update scores (first turns) + (last vs)))
          remain (if higher-odds?
                   (rest vs)
                   (butlast vs))]
      (recur scores (rest turns) remain))
    (prn scores)))
;; {:player-1 2624, :player-2 2326}
```

I'm not sure if this preserves your original game logic but it should be close, and it does generalize it for more than two players. Try adding `:player-3 0` to the starting `scores`.

Comment: That last piece of code you wrote... I'm not sure what it's doing. But I do know it's not working when I wrap it in a function with a parameter `v` and replace all the instances of `vs` (except for the first one) with `v`.